# continuity on co-countable topology

Tags: general-topology

Please help me..
I am looking for function like this $$f:\mathbb{R}_\text{co-count}\to \mathbb{R}$$ which is continuous but is not a constant function.
Can any one give me an example?

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that $f(a)=p$ and $f(b)=q$ where $p\ne q$. Let $D_p$ and $D_q$ be disjoint open disks with centres $p$ and $q$ respectively. Then $f^{-1}(D_p)$ and $f^{-1}(D_q)$ are disjoint, non-empty, and co-countable, which is impossible.

Answer (score 2):

Such a function does not exist.

Let $f$ be a function with e.g. $0,1\in f\left(\mathbb{R}\right)$. Suppose $f$ is continuous and let $D_0,D_1$ be disjoint open sets containing $0$ and $1$ respectively. 
Then $f^{-1}\left(D_0 \right)$ and
$f^{-1}\left(D_1\right)$ must be disjoint sets both
having a countable complement. Then $f^{-1}\left(D_0\right)$
as a subset of the complement of $f^{-1}\left(D_1\right)$
is countable and consequently $\mathbb{R}=f^{-1}\left(D_0 \right)\cup f^{-1}\left(D_0\right)^{c}$ is countable. Contradiction.